# write a unit test of this controller in angularjs which is calling a angularjs factory $http method

Tags: angularjs

1.**signup.js:**

```
function register() { 
    UserService.signup($scope.user).then(function (resp){ //$scope.user contain a json object
        if(resp.success){
        }
    });
}
```

2.**UserService.js**:

```
function signup(data) {
    return $http.post('/api/appusers', data)    
           .then(function (res) {
            },function(err) { 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing `$http` you can use Angular `$httpBackend` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend